# Is there an easy way to read integer time data from a netcdf file using the time-attribute?

Tags: matlab, date, attributes, netcdf

I am trying to read time-coordinate data from a netCDF file using matlab.  I have a netCDF file (which I created) that has a time variable in the format of a double corresponding to the number of hours from a specific time (see below).

**Variable attributes:**

```
    double time(Time) ;
            time:standard_name = "Time" ;
            time:units = "hours since 2002-01-01 0:0:0" ;
            time:calendar = "proleptic_gregorian" ;
```

When I read the time variable using ncread) into matlab, it just prints out an integer e.g.,1.  However, if I use "ncdump" to explore the file, I see the time variable in it's coordinate time e.g., 2002-01-01 01.

**Specifically:**  "ncdump -t -v time ncfile.nc"

I'm relatively new to matlab, and I was wondering if anyone knew if there was a similar, or an equally simple, way to read this time variable as its coordinate time into matlab, either as a string, or numerical date. Specifically, I would like to avoid having to parse the attribute string and code up a bunch of pointers and conditions to convert the integer data to an actual date.

Alternatively, should I just create a new time variable in these files that is just an array of dates as strings?

Any information is very much appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NetCDF stores time as an offset from an [epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29#Computingen.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29#Computing).  From your variable attribute, your epoch is 2002-01-01 0:0:0, and the time is hours since then.  Matlab has a similar methodology called date numbers, although it is based off of days since an epoch (which they call pivot years).  There are two functions that you should look into: datenum and datestr.  The first converts a string into a date number and the other converts a date number into a date string.

You can convert your time variable into a compatible Matlab date number by dividing by 24 and then use the datestr function to format it however you like.  Here is a simple example:

```
>> time = [1;2;3;4];
>> datestr(time./24+datenum('2002-01-01 0:0:0'))
ans =
01-Jan-2002 01:00:00
01-Jan-2002 02:00:00
01-Jan-2002 03:00:00
01-Jan-2002 04:00:00
```

Look at the Matlab help files associated with the two functions and you can format the date output however you like.